# Zip a list with a 2d list in python

Tags: python

I have a list and a list of lists. I want to zip them and run a loop over the tuples.

For example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [[11, 12], [21, 22], [31, 32], [41, 42]]
```

I want to get the following as output and run a loop through each tuple.

```
output = [(1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 21), (2, 22), (3, 31), ... ...]
```

I tried to do the following but it didn't work.

```
for candidate, reference in zip(list1, zip(*list2)):
    print(candidate, reference)
```

Comment: `[(x, z) for x, y in zip(list1, list2) for z in y]`

Comment: Did what you tried not work?

Comment: can I use just one loop?

Comment: @WasiAhmad can you make guarantees about the size of the tuple? Because then you could.

Comment: `list1` and `list2` size is variable. what did you mean by size of the tuple? tuple is always two numbers.

Comment: That's what I mean, if the tuple is always a pair then it's straightforward:

Comment: how? suggest me a solution with a single loop. I tried one approach but that didn't work.

Comment: Is it always that `len(list1) == len(list2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with a single-loop, but it seems like a microoptimization to me...

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2 = [[11, 12], [21, 22], [31, 32], [41, 42]]
>>> output = []
>>> for x, (a,b)  in zip(list1, list2):
...     output.append((x,a))
...     output.append((x,b))
...
>>> output
[(1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 21), (2, 22), (3, 31), (3, 32), (4, 41), (4, 42)]
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but actually this is not serving my purpose. what if list2 looks like - `list2 = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33], [41, 42, 43]]`?

Comment: @WasiAhmad That's what I was trying to ask before, I forgot you had sublists instead of tuples. Do you have any guarantees about the size of the sublists?

Comment: @WasiAhmad then the most sensible approach is to go with the "flat-map" idiom in python: `[(x, e) for x, y in zip(list1, list2) for e in y]`